# How do I add a watermark to multiple images using bitmap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to add text watermark to multiple images from a directory and save it to a directory. Here is what I have so far:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

namespace something.Controllers
{

    public class something: Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string text, string text1)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\name\Desktop\Images");
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles();
            string value = text;
            string value1 = text1;
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {


                using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap( file.FullName))
                {
                    using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                    {
                        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                        Font font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic, 
                        GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        SizeF textSize = new SizeF();
                        textSize = graphics.MeasureString(value, font);
                        Point position = new Point(bitmap.Width - ((int)textSize.Width + 
                        30), bitmap.Height - ((int)textSize.Height + 10));
                        graphics.DrawString((value + value1), font, brush, position);
                        using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            mStream.Position = 0;
                            bitmap.Save(mStream, ImageFormat.Png);



                            string _path = 
                            Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFolders"), 
                            file.Name);
                            bitmap.Save(_path);
                            return File(mStream.ToArray(), "image/png", file.Name);
                        }
                    }
                }



            }
            return View();
        }

    }

}
```

This code take user input and append it to the image this part works fine.
The issue:
 With this code it goes to the path and only add a water mark to the first image in the folder and save it. Not all images.
Thank you

Comment: a) how is the view related to the problem? It's not. Please remove that part of the question. b) having a `return` statement inside a `foreach` loop doesn't sound like a good idea

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp please point me to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply needed to remove this line:

```
return File(mStream.ToArray(), "image/png", file.Name);
```

Code works good and is another reference if someone needs it.

Answer (score 1):

Below Code works :

```
public void watermarkImage(string sourceImage, string text, string targetImage, ImageFormat fmt) {

        try
        {
            // open source image as stream and create a memorystream for output
            FileStream source = new FileStream(sourceImage, FileMode.Open);
            Stream output = new MemoryStream();
            Image img = Image.FromStream(source);

            // choose font for text
            Font font = new Font("Arial", 20, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

            //choose color and transparency
            Color color = Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 0, 0);

            //location of the watermark text in the parent image
            Point pt = new Point(10, 5);
            SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color);

            //draw text on image
            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img);
            graphics.DrawString(text, font, brush, pt);
            graphics.Dispose();

            //update image memorystream
            img.Save(output, fmt);
            Image imgFinal = Image.FromStream(output);

            //write modified image to file
            Bitmap bmp = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, img.PixelFormat);
            Graphics graphics2 = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            graphics2.DrawImage(imgFinal, new Point(0, 0));
            bmp.Save(targetImage, fmt);

            imgFinal.Dispose();
            img.Dispose();



        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: so i would call this method in my action result? to get the path of the folder i want to edit its images.